# Lift and shift SSIS to Azure Data Factory using VS but no subscriptions shown

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am moving some resources to the Azure cloud and am currently trying to do a lift and shift migration of our SSIS packages. I have the SSIS project loaded into Visual Studio 2019 and my Azure account login in but when I try to connect it to Azure, it is not showing any subscriptions. I have mostly been following this:
https://www.sqlshack.com/move-local-ssis-packages-to-azure-data-factory/
https://www.sqlshack.com/lift-and-shift-ssis-packages-using-azure-data-factory-v2/
I am a bit new to SSIS and Azure. I right click on the project in the solution explorer> SSIS in Azure Data Factory> Azure Enabled Product/Connect to SSIS in Azure Data Factory and go through the wizard but when I get to the "Select SSIS IR in ADF" part, there are no subscriptions in the dropdown. I don't get an errors. I thought I needed the Data Factory Contributor role based on some reading I did but it is still empty.

[image]

I decided to create a free trial Azure with a personal account and the subscription shows just fine. There is a data factory and a subscription for the account that isn't working, as well as an IR. Maybe the subscription isn't for this but I don't know much about how that works. I was also able to create a new data factory and IR in Azure. I'm just not sure what is missing. I've spent the last week reading and researching and have come up empty. I'd appreciate any help or insight anyone can offer. Thanks.

Comment: Smells like a permission issue on the subscription. What permission you'd need, I have no idea but take it up with your admin since you've proved the click path works for a sub you own

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the admin would be much help. I can put in a ticket for access but they won't know what access I need. I can try though.

Comment: It's likely a Contributor role to the ADF but I don't have any current clients with ADF to check that